# Two similar web pages, use one/two controller(s)? and why?

Tags: jakarta-ee, controller

Currently we are developing applications using JEE and we have a debate in our department about a point.

Suppose we have two web pages that are very similar in their functionalities with slight differences. In term of future maintenance or possible changes in the code is it better to :

- Have one controller to manage these two web pages and use `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();` to know which web page we are dealing with to apply specific instructions to each web page.
- OR, it is better to have two controllers, one controller for each web page. In this case we will duplicate a large number of lines, but we will not have to deal with tests to know if we are in web page 1 or web page 2.

It would be nice of you guys if you can give us the best approach and why we should follow it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first approach so the overhead of copying second controller is eliminated. Also if you introduce a similar change which is applicable to both webpages you have to implement that change in both the controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Aurvaa. Is not it a standard in JEE to have a controller per web page? and please be noticed that here I used webpage 1 and webpage 2, it is possible to have more webpages that use a same controller.